# grpc fails to load in electron - could not locate proto files

Tags: electron, grpc

OK I've got an electron app (5.0.6) which relies on GRPC node lib.
Dev build works fine.

Prod build, however, fails. I can run a successful prod build and create a windows installer, mac dmg etc. But when I start the app, only a blank screen appears. And I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'google/protobuf/api.proto'
```

This file exists in node_modules, it's used by one of the dependencies (protobufs.js).
The same code runs fine with dev builds. But it always fails in production (on all platforms)

How can I solve this? Is this caused by the asar archive the prod build creates?

Thanks in advance